# algebrainc proof for $\alpha\beta \leq \frac{\alpha^p}{p} + \frac{\beta^q}{q}$ for conjugate exponents p and q

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I found a very informal proof (geometric one, for by taking $\alpha$ as $\beta$ in the x-axis and y-axis and showing rectangle area is smaller than area under the plots).  Is there a proper algebraic proof for the inequality ?

$$
\alpha\beta \leq \frac{\alpha^p}{p} + \frac{\beta^q}{q}
$$
where $\alpha, \beta > 0$
$$
\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1
$$

Comment: Would taking integrals count as an algebraic proof? I think that it will be very close to the geometric proof...

Comment: Just search for [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products). There is also a proof on the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positives our $p$ and $q$ it's just AM-GM:
$$\frac{1}{p}\alpha^p+\frac{1}{q}\beta^q\geq\left(\alpha^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\beta^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}=\alpha\beta$$

Answer (score 3):

You might use the convexity of $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+,t\mapsto \exp(t)$:
$$\alpha\beta=\exp(\log(\alpha)+\log(\beta))=\exp(\frac{1}{p}\log(\alpha^p)+\frac{1}{q}\log(\alpha^q))\underbrace{\leq}_{convex. of \exp}$$$$\frac{1}{p}\exp(\log(\alpha^p))+\frac{1}{q}\exp(\log(\beta^q))=\frac{1}{p}\alpha^p+\frac{1}{q}\beta^q$$
which is not really proper algebraic, but hopefully clearer and more rigorous than the proof You read.